# Is higher or lower ALS.checkpointInterval better?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

When setting `ALS.checkpointInterval`, what consideration should be taken in setting it? What does a higher or lower interval mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALS.checkpointInterval** value refers the iterations for how many no. of times cache will be checkpointed.
E.g. If interval is set to 10 means that the cache will get checkpointed every 10 iterations.

Checkpointing helps with recovery (when nodes fail) and StackOverflow exceptions caused by long lineage. It also helps with eliminating temporary shuffle files on disk, which can be important when there are many ALS iterations.

Default value is **10**. So according to your system memory, you can set the lower or higher value now